# C# Nest elasticsearch динамический тип Search<>

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, типы

Есть `Events`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все `Events` наследуются от `BaseEvent`.

Скажем так: из `Utils.ConstructEvent(update, ts)` я получаю некоторый `Event`.

```
var readyUpdate = Utils.ConstructEvent(update, ts);
```

Далее, по этому `Event` мне нужно делать запрос в `elastic`, но тут вылезает подводный камень:

```
_elastic.Search<???>();
```

Я не понимаю как передать в `TDocument` метода `Search()` тип `Event` из `readyUpdate`.

То-есть, предположим в `readyUpdate` придет экземпляр класса `GotOnlineEvent`.
Тогда мне нужно будет написать `Search<GotOnlineEvent>()`.

Написать `_elastic.Search<readyUpdate.GetType()>` я очевидно не могу.

Пытался сделать по аналогии с `List<>`, но там все в разы проще, поскольку есть удобный интерфейс `IList`.

Comment: там разве нет перегрузки, принимающей Type? только обобщенная?

Comment: @aepot, где именно мне попытаться найти данную перегрузку?

Comment: F12 нажать на нужном методе или в документации